# Laravel: how to get access to a model by a relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have got following table structure

```
-user
--id
--name

-email
--id
--emailname
--username

-mails
--id
--sender_id
--receiver_id
--titel
--content
```

And I want to realize, that a user can have access to his email and get emails where he is sender or receiver. I'm not really sure if I can do following (if relations are made (one to many: mail and user, one to many: emails to mail) to get all mails for the user

```
Auth::user()->email->allMails
```

Thanks in advance!

greetings, rob

Comment: allMails will be a scope with ```where('sender_id',Auth::user()->id)->orWhere('receiver_id,Auth::user()->id)``` in the Mail-Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a function to the User model

```
public function allMails() {
    return Mail::where('sender_id', $this->id)
        ->orWhere('receiver_id', $this->id)
        ->get();
}
```

And then you can get all emails for the logged in account using `Auth::user()->allMails();`

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I guess if i want to replace the user id with the email id i have to put it to email model?